# insert made instead of update resulting in duplicate rows. how to fix?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database where is supposed to have only one register with 2 value columns that can be filled by my web application. The values to one of the columns where given to me in an excel and we had to put it into the database. The person who did that, should had used an "update if exists else insert" but he didn't. Now, we have for some data, duplicate lines, one having just the column "valor_realizado_oficial" filled (with the column adt_login filled with 'talend' and with the key columns filled too), and another with the other column filled by the application.
So:
If exists two lines, I would like to copy the value of the column "valor_realizado_oficial" from the line with adt_login like 'talend' to the other line and delete this line.
If exists just one line, do nothing.

I tried to perform the copy part with:

```
update indicador_val iv 
  set valor_realizado_oficial=carga.valor_realizado_oficial 
  from (
      select valor_realizado_oficial, ano, municipio_fk, indicador_fk, und_federativa_fk 
         from indicador_val 
         where adt_login like 'talend' and ano=2013 ) carga 
  where iv.ano=2013 and iv.municipio_fk=carga.municipio_fk 
      and iv.indicador_fk=carga.indicador_fk and iv.ano=carga.ano 
      and iv.und_federativa_fk = carga.und_federativa_fk;
```

But 0 rows where affected. Here's an example of a pair of lines:

> id; adt_login; ano; valor_estimado, valor_realizado_oficial, indicador_fk, municipio_fk, und_federativa_fk
>
> 313885; "talend";2013;;888;2;2202;
>
> 291998;"suagenda";2013;900;;2;2202;

And I would like to have just the second, with values:

> 291998;"suagenda";2013;900;888;2;2202;

What I did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample data, there are empty columns. For example, the last one: `und_federativa_fk`.

Some of these columns are used in your joining conditions in the correlated UPDATE. If these empty values translate to the SQL NULL value, you should realize that `NULL=NULL` as a condition is going to be NULL, which means `false` in this context.

That alone might explain why no row get updated.

The solution is to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` as the comparison operator for values that may be null.

Example:

```
 where iv.ano=2013 and iv.municipio_fk IS NOT DISTINCT FROM carga.municipio_fk 
      and iv.indicador_fk IS NOT DISTINCT FROM carga.indicador_fk
      etc...
```

Comment: I didn't know that! Now I trying to figure out how to delete the useless lines.

Comment: got it with: `delete from indicador_val iv where exists 
(select * from indicador_val carga where carga.adt_login not like 'talend' and iv.adt_login like 'talend' 
      and iv.ano=2013 and iv.municipio_fk is not distinct from carga.municipio_fk 
      and iv.indicador_fk=carga.indicador_fk and iv.ano=carga.ano 
      and iv.und_federativa_fk is not distinct from carga.und_federativa_fk); ` What I do now, mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: @Debora: welcome to stackoverflow and yes, if the answer was correct, please mark it as accepted.